# map function is not getting called when you call toPromise function in an http request reponse

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-promise

I'm using Angular 4 and want to convert the response to json before returning the promise object

```
    return this.http.post(this.signInURL, params.toString(), requestOptions).map(res =>{
      console.log(res.json())
      return res.json();
    }).toPromise();
```

in the component I'm using await to get the reponse as such

```
let response = await this.authenticationService.login(credentials);
console.log("response",response)
```

but the map function is not calling there but I will get a promise then I need to manually convert the response to json in the component it self since the body of the response is in string format

what can i do to convert the reponse to json and get back the promise with the json reponse object

Comment: Are you using the newer HttpClient that replaces the old Http injection? I think the new one already parses json and returns a specified object.

Comment: thanks a lot, HttpClient gave me the result I wanted